# Fix invalid child element in WCF RIA with SOAP endpoint

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf-ria-services, xsd-validation

Is there anyway to fix the warning that Visual Studio flags when you try and add the SOAP endpoint to a WCF RIA service ?

```
The element 'system.serviceModel' has invalid child element 'domainServices'
```

I found one blog post, [Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/205849/484343.aspx), but the only "answer" in it just says edit the Visual Studio DotNetConfig.xsd, not actually what to do

Comment: Nope ... not tried it with the latest SP, nor the VS11 bits